# How to keep logged in User on 1 Craft Multi Site, but with different domains

Tags: craft3, localization, multi-site, cookies

I have one multisite craft installation, where the different languages for the sites use different domains:

en -> domain.com

de -> otherdomain.com
..

Users can log in via frontend.
Now if users log in and change the language, they get logged out.

i cannot use the [defaultCookieDomain](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#defaultCookieDomain) setting, because i dont have the same root domain.

According to this [post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/15121/single-sign-on-for-multiple-craft-sites/16360#16360), due to cross-domain restrictions, sites not sharing a root domain are not allowed to receive/read each other's cookies.

Is there another way of sharing the user's CraftSessionId cookie and thus preventing the user being logged out after changing the language?